react-native-vision-camera Crashes with -> maxImages (6) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring more
I have the following react-native-vision-camera Implementation in Android React Native :
const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor((frame) => {
'worklet'
}, [])

The App Crashes when I set isRevCameraActive to true

09-20 19:04:14.827 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer: java.lang.IllegalStateException: maxImages (6) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring more.

The StackTrace :

09-20 19:04:14.768 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer: Failed to
acquire image. 09-20 19:04:14.768 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: maxImages (6) has already been
acquired, call #close before acquiring more. 09-20 19:04:14.768 18105
18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:    at
android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextImage(ImageReader.java:527) 09-20
19:04:14.768 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:     at
androidx.camera.core.AndroidImageReaderProxy.acquireNextImage(AndroidImageReaderProxy.java:86)
09-20 19:04:14.768 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
androidx.camera.core.SafeCloseImageReaderProxy.acquireNextImage(SafeCloseImageReaderProxy.java:86)
09-20 19:04:14.768 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysisBlockingAnalyzer.acquireImage(ImageAnalysisBlockingAnalyzer.java:39)
09-20 19:04:14.768 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysisAbstractAnalyzer.onImageAvailable(ImageAnalysisAbstractAnalyzer.java:126)
09-20 19:04:14.768 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
androidx.camera.core.SafeCloseImageReaderProxy.lambda$setOnImageAvailableListener$1$androidx-camera-core-SafeCloseImageReaderProxy(SafeCloseImageReaderProxy.java:211)
09-20 19:04:14.768 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
androidx.camera.core.SafeCloseImageReaderProxy$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onImageAvailable(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
09-20 19:04:14.768 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
androidx.camera.core.AndroidImageReaderProxy.lambda$setOnImageAvailableListener$0$androidx-camera-core-AndroidImageReaderProxy(AndroidImageReaderProxy.java:167) 09-20 19:04:14.768 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:  at
androidx.camera.core.AndroidImageReaderProxy$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
09-20 19:04:14.768 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
09-20 19:04:14.768 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
09-20 19:04:14.768 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 09-20 19:04:14.790   906 18275 E
PDTblGen: [getTbl] dev(1) scenario(0) : Table is not generated. Please
check error log during generating table (1st time lunch sensor
mode(0)) 09-20 19:04:14.790   906 18275 E PDTblGen:
(getTbl){#778:vendor/mediatek/proprietary/hardware/mtkcam/aaa/source/common/utils/PDTblGen/PDTblGen.cpp}
09-20 19:04:14.790   906 18275 E isp_mgr_bnr: apply(): Fail to Gen PDC
Table, SensorDev(1), SensorMode(0), FrontBin(0) 09-20 19:04:14.790
906 18275 E isp_mgr_bnr:
(apply){#266:vendor/mediatek/proprietary/hardware/mtkcam/aaa/source/mt6765/isp_mgr/isp_mgr_bnr.cpp}
09-20 19:04:14.793 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer: Failed to
acquire image. 09-20 19:04:14.793 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: maxImages (6) has already been
acquired, call #close before acquiring more. 09-20 19:04:14.793 18105
18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:    at
android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextImage(ImageReader.java:527) 09-20
19:04:14.793 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:     at
androidx.camera.core.AndroidImageReaderProxy.acquireNextImage(AndroidImageReaderProxy.java:86)
09-20 19:04:14.793 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
androidx.camera.core.SafeCloseImageReaderProxy.acquireNextImage(SafeCloseImageReaderProxy.java:86)
09-20 19:04:14.793 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysisBlockingAnalyzer.acquireImage(ImageAnalysisBlockingAnalyzer.java:39)
09-20 19:04:14.793 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysisAbstractAnalyzer.onImageAvailable(ImageAnalysisAbstractAnalyzer.java:126)
09-20 19:04:14.793 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
androidx.camera.core.SafeCloseImageReaderProxy.lambda$setOnImageAvailableListener$1$androidx-camera-core-SafeCloseImageReaderProxy(SafeCloseImageReaderProxy.java:211)
09-20 19:04:14.793 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
androidx.camera.core.SafeCloseImageReaderProxy$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onImageAvailable(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
09-20 19:04:14.793 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
androidx.camera.core.AndroidImageReaderProxy.lambda$setOnImageAvailableListener$0$androidx-camera-core-AndroidImageReaderProxy(AndroidImageReaderProxy.java:167) 09-20 19:04:14.793 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:  at
androidx.camera.core.AndroidImageReaderProxy$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
09-20 19:04:14.793 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
09-20 19:04:14.793 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
09-20 19:04:14.793 18105 18387 E ImageAnalysisAnalyzer:   at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 09-20 19:04:14.825   906 18275 E
PDTblGen: [getTbl] dev(1) scenario(0) : Table is not generated. Please
check error log during generating table (1st time lunch sensor
mode(0)) 09-20 19:04:14.825   906 18275 E PDTblGen:
(getTbl){#778:vendor/mediatek/proprietary/hardware/mtkcam/aaa/source/common/utils/PDTblGen/PDTblGen.cpp}
09-20 19:04:14.825   906 18275 E isp_mgr_bnr: apply(): Fail to Gen PDC
Table, SensorDev(1), SensorMode(0), FrontBin(0) 09-20 19:04:14.825
906 18275 E isp_mgr_bnr:
(apply){#266:vendor/mediatek/proprietary/hardware/mtkcam/aaa/source/mt6765/isp_mgr/isp_mgr_bnr.cpp}

What am I missing ?
Thank you all in advance .
